# Convert and show data in mysql from 1252 to UTF-8

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I have one old database which I must use. The problem is that the old data(mostly text) is stored in 1252(latin1_general_ci) and is showed like `??????` on the page. Then I've converted whole database and the table to `UTF-8` collation like this:

```
ALTER DATABASE databasename CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE tablename CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

But the problem whit old records remains. I know that the queries above are just change the fields collation. My question is there an way to show those `?????` records properly on the web page now?

Comment: Welcome to character encoding hell ;) Changing the charset of a database is a relative complex problem. But I think this link could help you by debugging and solving your problem: http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/post/turning_mysql_data_in_latin1_t.html And just a little hint: Making a backup of your database is never wrong.

Comment: Thank's for the comment. Yeah, I've made backup of the database. Also I've made a copy of it and testing on the copy not on the production. I will check the link you provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Create dump

```
mysqldump --default-character-set=latin1 --skip-set-charset mydatabase mytable > ./mytable.sql
```

2) In mytable.sql replace latin1 in utf8

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` char(255) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

3) Import DB

```
mysql --user=login -p --database=mydatabase < ./mytable.sql
```

[mysqldump — A Database Backup Program](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html)

Comment: Can I do this in phpmyadmin since I don't have access to shell on my host?

Comment: Yes, export - advanced settings